# Assigning cells to variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have set a cell to a variable and then I have stored a cell address within the variable:

```
Dim sumOfLevel As String
sumOfLevel = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 5).Address
```

I now want to populate the cell and can't seem to get it to work. I have tried numerous techniques for example:

```
sumOfLevel.Value = "getting there"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can address your problem.

**Way 1**

```
Dim sumOfLevel As String

sumOfLevel = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & _
             ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 5).Address

With ActiveSheet.Range(sumOfLevel)
    '~~> Do Something
    .Value = "getting there"
End With
```

**Way 2**

```
Dim sumOfLevel As Range

Set sumOfLevel = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & _
                 ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 5)

With sumOfLevel 
    '~~> Do Something
    .Value = "getting there"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason, it is a very simple solution. If you want to save a reference to an object, you must use **Set**. Solution below

```
Dim sumOfLevel As Range
Set sumOfLevel = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 5)
sumOfLevel.Value = "getting there"
```

Comment: `sumOfLevel` should also be declared as a `Range` variable, not a `String`.